# Diablo III Acts and User Page disagree with each other on Acts 2-4

Tags: bug, status-completed, contests

The Diablo III Acts page lists 3 requirements for the latter 3 acts: 1+ voted questions, 5+ voted questions, and 10+ voted questions.

Our individual user pages, however, list 1+, 5+, and 8+.

I *think* that's just a typo in copy+pasting the ME3 mission code, <strike>and I don't know if it's visual (ie., it displays an 8, but only recognizes a 10) or</strike>   in the actual display code itself (it displays and requires only 8).

Just a heads up!

Edit: I can now confirm that the display code is only checking for 8+ and not 10+, as my user page lists me as having 1/1 8+ for Act 2 even though the answer in question ([this](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/66112/how-much-gold-does-it-take-to-unlock-all-crafting-recipes/66123#66123) has only 8 and not 10).

Comment: Was about to post this too, it happened the same to me with [this question](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/66266/is-there-any-achievement-that-gives-out-rewards). What's the actual value? 8 or 10?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fixed the typo on [diablo3acts.com](http://diablo3acts.com). The correct values are 1+, 5+, and 8+. Sorry about that. Thanks!